# Constraining width of html input type time on Android webview

Tags: android, input, webview

in IOS Webview, the input type="time" generates a time display widget that is approx 70 pixels wide and when tapped brings up the IOS time picker.

However in Android the same code brings up a 130 pixel wide widget that also brings up a timepicker, albeit a very different style of one. My problem is the widget is far too big for my user interface design to cope with, without a huge amount of re-work.

Does anyone know if it is possible to reduce the length of the time display widget in Android using CSS, or by reducing the fidelity of the time that could be displayed. or is it always set to match the length of the type="date" version.

Alternatively might it be possible to set its style to display:"none" and activate it using javascript by clicking elsewhere?. Has anyone tried this on Android webview?

Comment: I have found that you can reduce the width a bit by reducing the font size